# TensorFlow/TFLearn -Architecture Err - 'ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor u'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I tried tflearn Quickstart titanic tutorial successfully and made some tests further.
I was predicting a float target by 8 float inputs, and I modified some of the tutorial then 
'ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor u'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)''

## Build neural network

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 8])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='relu')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
```

## Define model

```
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0)
```

## Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)

```
model.fit(data, mfe, n_epoch=100)#Err occurs
```

Could somebody kindly help me:
1. What do 'shape (64,) ' and shape '(?, 1)' stand for?
2. How can I fix this Architecture Err?
3. Could you make some recommendation of materials learning neural networks architecture?

Thanks & Regards,
Simon

Comment: Always good to give a [mcve] along with your question...

Answer (score 2):

I have never used TensorFlow but I bet this is just a broadcasting issue. Try to change the shape of your problematic array which currently has shape (64,) into (64,1), that is from a row vector to a column vector:

```
my_array.shape = (64, 1)
```

or more generally for any length:

```
my_array.shape = (-1, 1)
```

You can read about shapes and broadcasting rules on the numpy documentation pages for more details. As for recommendation for neural networks architecture learning material, this is unfortunately off-topic (too opinion based) by SO rules.

Comment: Thanks!! This helped :)

Answer (score 1):

shape (64,) is the batch_size in the network model.Here tflearn uses 64, as its default.if you had given batch_size as 8 it would have been shape(8,)

shape (?, 1) is the output from your net.The titanic example was a classification problem and it had 2 classes,so it had 2 units in output

```
net=tflearn.reshape(net,[-1])
```

this should fix the issue . the -1 means none

make sure the reshaping is done before the estimator layer i.e tflearn.regression

Answer (score 0):

1) shape (64,) is the default batch_size,
shape (?, 1) is the output of your network that is used to determine the loss.

2) How can I fix this Architecture Err? 
Since your output is of shape (# of samples, 2)
your last layer should be

`net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='relu')`

3) Could you make some recommendation of materials learning neural networks 
architecture?
Udacity.com, Udemy.com have excellent courses on neural network, you can learn a lot for free